# Exponent of 1 in the extraspecial group

Tags: gr.group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\PO{P\Omega}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field with characteristic not equal 2.

Let $\PO_8(K)$ be the adjoint algebraic group of type $D_4$. It says a direct computation shows that there is an elementary abelian subgroup $X = 2^2$ such that $C_{\PO_8(K)}(X) = T_4\mathbin.2^{1+4}_+$.

Question: where does the exponent of 1 in the extraspecial group come from, and how does it act on $T_4$?

I was thinking:

There is $\SL_2(K)\circ_2 \SL_2(K)\circ_2 \SL_2(K)\circ_2 \SL_2(K)$ in $\PO_8(K)$ and there is a quaternion with generators $\{u_i,v_i\}$ in each $\SL_2(K)$. So if I let $X = \langle(u_1,u_2),(u_3,u_4)\rangle$, then I get that the $T_4$ are the centralizers of them in the $\SL_2$. Also, the four $v$'s should centralize $X$, hence the exponent of 4 in the extraspecial group, I suppose? Also, the four $v$'s induce inverse on the $T_4$.

Comment: You say "It says".  What is "it"?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the characteristic of $K$ is not $2$.

Comment: What is the paper that you are reading?

Comment: Let $G=P\Omega_8^+(K)$ and $\hat G=Spin_8^+(K)$, the universal version of $G$. It looks as though $T_4$ is a Cartan subgroup of $G$ and is normal in $C_G(X)$. Also, $T_4$ is the image in $G$ of a Cartan subgroup $\hat T_4$ of $\hat G$, and $X$ is the image in $G$ of the exponent $2$ subgroup of $\hat T_4$. The $2^{1+4}_+$ looks like $O_2(W)$, where $W$ is the Weyl group of type $D_4$.

Comment: Is $O_2$ maximal normal 2-subgroup of W?

Comment: Yes, $O_2(H)$ is the maximal normal $2$-subgroup of $H$, for any finite group $H$.